# Pronouncing the vav in mitzvot and matzot

Tags: hebrew

What is the reason for the different pronunciation of the vav in the words mitzvot and matzot?

Comment: The vav in *matzot* is not pronounced at all. It’s merely a vowel marker for the *tzadi*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Different words have different ways of pronouncing them. I imagine that's true in all languages.

Comment: @DoubleAA  There are general pronunciation rules.  There must be two rules that apply to these two words, as they are pronounced differently.  What are those rules?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think they should be pronounced the same?

Comment: @DoubleAA Typically letters have a sound.  Here the same letter has two sounds  I seek a rule that applies.

Comment: Look carefully: in מִצְוֹת there is a sheva indicating that the following consonant (ו) is to be pronounced, in מַצּוֹת‎ there is no such.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  The possible ambiguity is the subject of a teaching in the Midrash.  The Torah says:

And you shall watch over the matzot. [Ex. 12:17]

The Midrash says:

Rabbi Yoshiyah says: Do not read אֶת-הַמַצּוֹת, [watch over] the matzot, but אֶת-הַמִצְוֹת, [watch over] the commandments. [The letters are the same, but the vowels are different.] Just as we may not allow the matzot to become leavened, so we may not allow the commandments to become leavened [by waiting too long to perform them].  If [a commandment] comes your way, perform it immediately.  [Mechilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 12:17]

Thus, the deeper lesson is that we must be prompt in performing all commandments.  The Maharal notes that if the Torah only wanted to talk about matzah, it would have stated “Watch for ḥametz”, that is, make sure sure the matzah is not contaminated. Since the Torah said “Watch over the matzot”, there must be a deeper meaning. So a teaching is needed: Mitzvot must be performed with alacrity, promptly and with cheerful readiness.

Answer (score 0):

The letter "vav" in Hebrew can sometimes stand for either of the two vowels made with the lips--Cholam (ö) and Shuruq (w).

A vav is pronounced as the Cholam-vowel if it has a single dot right above it. It appears as ״וֹ״.

It is pronounced as Shuruq when 1: the letter before it has no other vowel or itself does not exist, and 2: it has a dot (dagesh) right next to it, appearing as ״וּ״. Please note that if either of the above criteria are not met, it is a normal Vav sound.

(In Biblical Hebrew, normal Vav is somewhere between shuruq and a V-sound made with the tongue. In modern Hebrew, it is a simple V-sound.)